# how to make checks in xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

i have method which create xml:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();

var head = xml.CreateElement("Head");
var uniqueIdentifier = xml.CreateElement("Unique_identifier");
var documentDate = xml.CreateElement("Document_date");
var documentNumber = xml.CreateElement("Document_number");

uniqueIdentifier.InnerText = "1";
documentDate.InnerText = "2019-01-01";
documentNumber.InnerText = "2";

xml.AppendChild(head);
head.AppendChild(uniqueIdentifier);
head.AppendChild(documentDate);
head.AppendChild(documentNumber);
```

InnerText Values i get from db and this fields can be null or empty. so, each variable needs checked for null and an empty string
like this

```
    var uniqueIdentifier = xml.CreateElement("Unique_identifier");
    var r = reader.GetFieldValue("Unique_identifier");
    if (r is string)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r))
        {
            uniqueIdentifier.InnerText = Text.Convert(r);
        }
    }
```

I get a lot of extra lines(5 variable and 10 check). How clean it?

Comment: Where do you get the extra lines? in the xml file?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "extra lines". What I see is you will have duplicate code if you just copy exactly this for each field you need in the xml. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Select `"Unique_identifier"`, press Ctrl + `.`, choose "introduce local". Select the block (without the local), press Ctrl + `.`, choose "extract method". Voila, one reusable bit of usefulness. Recent versions of C# allow you to make the method local so you don't have to pass the `xml` and `reader`.